# How to map shorthanded routes to the same controller in Slim 3

Tags: php, rest, routes, url-routing, slim

I am working on a REST API project using Slim 3, and I was wondering if there is an easy way to implement the following routing without creating separate routes for the shorthands.

The shorthand is `../me` for `../users/{id}` where the `id` is the current users ID.
So far its easy, I just create the two routes, and map them to the same controller method; but there are many more endpoints which use the same logic for example:
`../users/{id}/posts` should use the same as `../me/posts`,
`../users/{id}/groups/{gid}` should use the as `../me/groups/{gid}`, etc.

I used the double dots to indicate that there are preceding URI parts (version, language etc.).
I hope you get the idea now.

So my question is this: is there a way to reroute these kind of requests, or maybe is there a route pattern that would fit my needs and i missed it, maybe even I have to fiddle in a middleware to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: What about putting the id in a session and then when you hit me as a variable you get that out?

Comment: thats not how REST works

Comment: Ah yes sorry solving the route not the problem. That what I get for poking around during a meeting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to take advantage of Slim's [FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute) router. Put a regular expression into the variable part of your route and do the extra parsing inside the controller:

```
$app->get('/whatever/{id:users/\d+|me}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    if (preg_match('%^users/(\d+)$%', $args['id'], $parsed)) {
        // This is /users/{id} route:
        $user = $parsed[1];
    } else {
        // This is /me route:
        $user = 'automagically recognized user';
    }
    return $response->withStatus(200)->write('Hello '.$user);
});
```

However I'd find that strange and would recommend mapping the same controller to two individual routes, as you do now. Two reasons come to my mind:

- You can put the user ID lookup for 'me' route only into the one where it's needed (by having another controller adding this logic on top of the main one).
- It's easier to comprehend for other developers on the team.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
$app->get('/users[/{id}/groups[/{msgid}]]', function ($request, $response, $args) {
}
```

and see the oficial documentation in http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html

Comment: i cannot imagine this would also work for "/me/groups/{msgid}"